# How do I find custom object records and connected objects?

Tags: custom-object, custom, record, object

I have recently been tasked with going through all of our custom objects and deleting the ones that aren't used. Being relatively new to Salesforce, I'm having a bit of difficulty finding if the custom object is connected to another object, if it has any pertinent records, or the last time it was used. Is there an easier way to obtain this information other than going through reports?

Comment: Field trip might be one tool you could use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have been using the Field Trip app and it has helped me find quite a few objects that don't have any connections or records so those ones I know for sure I can delete.

Answer (score 0):

Workbench.Developerforce.com may be more helpful to you. You can look at the fields on the custom object to look for object Ids which will let you know which objects it is connected to. I think the section is called Standard and Custom Objects. Click on the desired object to look at its features. There is also Schema Builder in the Setup section of Salesforce. You can find the object you need and you will be able to see everything it is connected to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried the Workbench but I kept getting an error: "UNKNOWN ERROR: Could not find Terms of Service."

I tried the Schema Builder as well but our production environment is so convoluted with objects that it's hard to find the connections.

Comment: @JeffBoyd try workbench again today. It was down on Friday. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Workbench is down right now.

You can use Deveopler Console.  It's next to your name in drop down menu.

In Dev Console, File->open resources I believe.

Not good as workbench but will get you going.

Of course all custom objects add __c at the end of their name.